# PDO - Number of rows - is this the shortest way?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I realise there are numerous posts about obtaining number of rows in PDO from a select.. boring!!

BUT... I'm trying to do it in as little amount of rows as possible and still be able to use the recordset in a loop afterwards. How is this?

```
$sql =  "SELECT Name FROM my_table WHERE LastName = 'Wilson' ";

$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    echo $row['Id'];

}
```

I've tried so many combinations... but I seem to have to double up on **$stmt = $conn->query($sql);** to be able to use the loop after? Can this be improved?

Comment: In one word: terrible. You're executing the same query twice and are fetching all data twice, once even all into memory at once.

Comment: This is bad. You are 1) doing `SELECT *`, which is bad form, and 2) you are pulling ALL data twice. Just use `COUNT(*)` to get number of rows first.

Comment: ...and without a `WHERE` clause, which is really bad, if the tables are running the INNO engine.

Comment: pdo rowcount() is only for this

Comment: Oh crikey! I removed my sensitive data contained in my ACTUAL select statement and just added a SELECT *! That part of the question was actually irrelevant. Anyway, it turns out ->rowcount works just fine with mysql on selects, contrary to what many people on the web say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the deal with this whole rowcount() thing to be honest.

I have a live site and if I do:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT type FROM vehicles WHERE del='N'");
echo $stmt->rowcount();
```

it returns 46, which is correct.

This works fine on both my dev server and my hosting server.

As far as I can work out, rowcount() only doesn't work if you are using a COUNT() in your query. No doubt someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: When you're using a `COUNT()` it'll still work correctly: it'll tell you `1`, because aggregate queries return 1 row. It always works the same.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, you are quite correct - "doesn't work" was a poor choice of words on my part, I should maybe edit that to say "doesn't work as some people expect." ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm connecting to a mysql database and it works fine! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM my_table ";

$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$row_count = count($results);

foreach ($results as $row) {

    echo $row['Id'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say here. You either fetch the resulting data and then count the rows in PHP, or you store the query and run it twice - once with your actual `SELECT` and once with `SELECT COUNT(*)`. That's no big deal, if the query is using an index.